# How to use global to $GLOBALS

Tags: php, global

I cannot understand GLOBALS ! this time chg SRC for 4.3 to 7.0 !
But I cannot use GLOBALS. Single is ok, but 2 values are not replaced.

OLD is

```
globals $chk_data ;
<?php if ( $chk_data[$i] == 1 ) { ?>
```

NEW is ?

```
$GLOBALS['chk_data'] ;
<?php if ( $GLOBALS['chk_data']['i'] == 1 ) { ?>
```

or

```
<?php if ( $GLOBALS['chk_data'][$i] == 1 ) { ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need try like this.because `$GLOBALS['']` expect a value.but you didn't provide any value.here if `$i=1` then condition will be true.

```
$GLOBALS['chk_data']=$i ;
<?php if ( $GLOBALS['chk_data'] == 1 ) { ?>
```

Comment: There is another way to use [$ i] when using global variables.
I will try various things. However, what I am doing now is taken over by other stuff. (I got fired.)
Thank you for everything.